# Is my implementation of multi-threading okay?

Tags: java, multithreading

I built an application class that should be runnable as a `Thread` and it would be nice to hear opinions of Java developers to improve my coding style.

`Main` class.

```
package com.ozankurt;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application application = new Application();

        application.start();

    }
}
```

Application class:

```
package com.ozankurt;

import com.ozankurt.utilities.Input;

public class Application implements Runnable {

    private CommandHandler commandHandler;

    private boolean running;

    private volatile Thread thread;
    private String threadName = "ApplicationThread";

    public Application() {

        Handler handler = new Handler(this);

        this.commandHandler = new CommandHandler(handler);

        this.running = true;
    }

    public void start() {

        if (thread != null) {
            System.out.println(threadName + "is already running.");

            if (!isRunning())
            {
                System.out.println("Resuming " + threadName + "...");
                setRunning(true);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Starting " + threadName + "...");

            thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
            thread.start();

            System.out.println("Started " + threadName + ".");
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Halting " + threadName + "...");

        setRunning(false);

        System.out.println("Halted " + threadName + ".");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (isRunning()) {
            String userInput = Input.readLine();

            commandHandler.handle(userInput);
        }
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {

        return running;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {

        this.running = running;
    }
}
```

I read this [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) about how to stop threads in Java without using `stop` method that has become deprecated because it might throw some exceptions.

As far as I understand we shouldn't try to stop a thread and instead we should define a property corresponding to the state of the thread.

In my case I defined a `boolean running` in my `Application` class and as you can read from my code in the `run` method I basicly check if the application is `running`. Which mean that I actually never stop the thread, I only remove its functionality by using a `while` statement. Is this the correct approach explained in the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)?

Comment: Who needs to start/stop this thread? Why can't they make sure that they only start one of them? What does the application do? Where is the multi-threading part (can you run more than one of these? If so, how do they all read from Input)? Without that, it is not clear what needs to be done.

Comment: @Thilo I just updated that part of my code, can you please check again and have a look at the `title` of my edit from the edit history.

Comment: The `Application` basicly waits for a user input from command line and runs the related command accordingly.

Comment: You might want to have a look at codereview.stackexchange.com, as questions asking *to improve my coding style* are usually off-topic here :)

Comment: @T3H40 Thank you, I will do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't put a start/stop method on a Runnable, it's just messing with the reader! LOL! And don't have this runnable try to manage it's own thread, it's even more confusing.

Anyhow, 1st issue will be the missing volatile on the 'running' boolean.

2nd issue is that your main() ends while you started a thread. It works, sure, but that shows you didn't need any thread at all. The main() thread could have called some Application.loopOnCommands() or similar.

3rd, the stop() doesn't interrupt the thread. I'm assuming the readLine() can block and the handle(...) method can be long, so signaling the interrupt can wake up waiting threads. This is not always going to force a thread out of the code, but it can help if that code is honoring the possibility for interruptions.